# Read section based values from properties file in robots framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am a newbie for robots framework development.
I have some values files with section-based. The values file example is below

```
[VALID_USER]
username = userone  
password = userone

[INVALID_USER]
username = usertwo
password = usertwo
```

I need to access this file contents in the robot file. For example, ${VALID_USER.username}. But I am not able to find a proper way to do this. Does the robots framework provide support to this?

Could anyone help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advavnce

Comment: What library are you using to read the properties file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently, I don't know which library should I use. Could you please suggest any better library?